# Opening a component changes overall style of the App- Mui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Mui and Material kit theme to build a project..
I am using the theme provided by Material kit and i am also using custom css to modify some features of the default components provided by Material kit, but  I am unable to overrride the styles.. So right now i am stuck with default theme provided by Material kit
But recently i added another component in my app, and i noticed that whenever i open that component the overall styling of the app changes, which to my surprise were the custom styles i provided, which were'nt working before..
My question is-
What might be the reason for this behaviour

Any help would be greatly appreciated

This is my App.js

```js
import './App.css';
// @mui material components
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
// Material Kit 2 React themes
import theme from "assets/theme";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomeSkeleton from 'components/Drawer/Drawer';
import SignInCover from 'components/sign-in/Signin';
import DSAManagement from 'components/DSAManagement/DSAManagement';
import LeadManagement from 'components/LeadManagement/LeadManagement';
import ResponsiveDrawer from 'components/Drawer/ResponsiveDrawer';
import NotificationsComp from 'components/notifications/NotificationsComp';
import Notifications from 'components/common/Notifications/Notifications';

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/' element={<SignInCover/>} />
          <Route exact path='/res' element={<ResponsiveDrawer/>}></Route>
          <Route exact path='/home' element={<HomeSkeleton/>} >
            <Route exact path='dsa-management' element={<DSAManagement />}/>
            <Route exact path='lead-management' element={<LeadManagement />}/>
            <Route exact path='payout-management' element={<DSAManagement />}/>
            <Route exact path='product-management' element={<DSAManagement />}/>
            <Route exact path='notifications' element={<NotificationsComp />}/>
            <Route exact path='user-notifications' element={<Notifications />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is the troubling component

```js
import React from 'react'
import { TextareaAutosize, Toolbar } from '@material-ui/core'
import { Box } from '@material-ui/core'
import { Icon } from '@material-ui/core'
import { IconButton } from '@material-ui/core'
import { AccessTime, Bookmark } from '@material-ui/icons'
import { Button, Grid } from '@mui/material'
import NotificationTabs from './NotificationTabs'

const NotificationsComp = () => {
    return(
    <>
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item md={12}>
        <Toolbar disableGutters sx={{padding: 0}}>
          <Box sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}>
          <IconButton size="medium" aria-label="filter" color="inherit">
              <Icon>filterList</Icon>
          </IconButton>
          <Button variant="text" color='black' 
              sx={{
                  display: 'inline-block', 
                  fontSize: '0.8rem', p:0, 
                  mr: '1rem',
                  letterSpacing: 0}}>
                  Filter
              </Button>
          <Button variant="text" color='black' 
              sx={{
                  display: 'inline-block', 
                  fontSize: '0.8rem', p:0, 
                  mr: '1rem',
                  letterSpacing: 0}}>
                  (500 DSA selected)
              </Button>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item md={12}>
        <TextareaAutosize  style={{height: '10rem',width: '100%', padding: '1rem'}} placeholder={'Write Notification Text here'}></TextareaAutosize>
        <Toolbar disableGutters>
          <Box sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' }, px: 0 }} >
            <IconButton size="medium" aria-label="show 4 new mails" color="inherit">
              <Icon>send</Icon>
            </IconButton>
            <Button variant="text" color='black' 
              sx={{
                display: 'inline-block', 
                fontSize: '0.8rem', p:0, 
                mr: '1rem',
                letterSpacing: 0}}>
                  Send Notification
            </Button>
            <IconButton
            size="medium"
            aria-label="show 17 new notifications"
            color="inherit"
            >
              <AccessTime/>
            </IconButton>
            <Button variant="text" color='black' 
              sx={{
                display: 'inline-block', 
                fontSize: '0.8rem', p:0, 
                mr: '1rem',
                letterSpacing: 0}}>
                  Schedule
            </Button>
            <IconButton
              size="medium"
              aria-label="save notifications"
              color="inherit"
            >
            <Bookmark/>
            </IconButton>
            <Button variant="text" color='black' 
              sx={{
                display: 'inline-block', 
                fontSize: '0.8rem', p:0, 
                mr: '1rem',
                letterSpacing: 0}}>
                  Save
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item md={12}>
        <NotificationTabs/>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
    </>    
    )
}
export default NotificationsComp
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal working prototype using something like [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

---

**Reason ->**

The overall css was changing because the component in question had different import paths for mui components than the paths that were set in the rest of the components, app-wide.

**Explaination ->**
Take for example if ->

In rest of the components Box was imported from '@mui/material/Box, but in NotificationsComp component it was imported from '@material-ui/core. So when this component loaded it introduced some more css classes which overrided the existing css classes for these components and hence the change in css.

So setting the same paths for mui components in the `<NotificationsComp/>` as the rest of the app fixed the problem.